# Couldnt find solution for - Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android

I have tried everything what i found while googling but still have a mistake.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbut.class

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'



    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'



}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your "multidex" dependency and "multiDexEnabled true" in debug flavor.

Comment: What i have to do to fix it?

Comment: either use dependency or the attribute in debug flavor

Comment: can you describe it in more details please?